# How can I throttle stack of api requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, underscore.js, throttling

I have an array of ids, and I want to make an api request for each id, but I want to control how many requests are made per second, or better still, have only 5 open connections at any time, and when a connection is complete, fetch the next one.

Currently I have this, which just fires off all the requests at the same time:

```
_.each([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], function(issueId) {
    github.fetchIssue(repo.namespace, repo.id, issueId, filters)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log('Writing: ' + issueId);
            writeIssueToDisk(fetchIssueCallback(response));
        });
});
```

Comment: You want capped concurrency promises. Take a look at [ES6 Promise Pool](https://github.com/timdp/es6-promise-pool), and also the list of Alternatives specified on that page. Or, you can implement your own counting semaphore :D

Comment: I faced a similar problem, I needed to rate limit chat messages coming through. There is an algorithm called the "Leaky Bucket". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket I think this is similar to what you are facing.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has mentioned [async](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/README.md). Your "ideal" request sounds like a job for [eachLimit](https://github.com/caolan/async#each)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: I am surprised no-one read my link - the Alternatives at ES6 Promise Pool clearly lists async's `queue()`.

Comment: @Amadan you'll have to redefine "clearly" for me, then. That's like the equivalent of expecting me to read fine-print.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I'd use Bluebird's `.map()` with the `concurrency` option since I'm already using promises and Bluebird for anything async.  But, if you want to see what a hand-coded counter scheme that restricts how many concurrent requests can run at once looks like, here's one:

```
function limitEach(collection, max, fn, done) {
    var cntr = 0, index = 0, errFlag = false;

    function runMore() {
        while (!errFlag && cntr < max && index < collection.length) {
            ++cntr;
            fn(collection[index++], function(err, data) {
                --cntr;
                if (errFlag) return;
                if (err) {
                    errFlag = true;
                    done(err);
                } else {
                   runMore();
                }
            });
        }
        if (!errFlag && cntr === 0 && index === collection.length) {
            done();
        }
    }
    runMore();
}
```

Comment: This is excellent stuff. I am using Q, now I am trying to figure out how to simplify this utility with promises - there is no equivalent to map with concurrency in Q right?

Comment: Not in Q itself, but see [qlimit](https://github.com/suprememoocow/qlimit) which adds it to Q (and is like 20 lines of code itself). Also, you might consider migrating to Bluebird - API is very similar, and there's other [reasons](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/63#issuecomment-34140791).

Comment: I know this is an old question. I have used this very nice function and modified it to use async/await and for using the same limit for multiple functions (the limit can thus be applied at endpoint level or api level or both). Adding that as a seperate answer as it won't be contained in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

With Bluebird:

```js
function fetch(id) {
  console.log("Fetching " + id);
  return Promise.delay(2000, id)
  .then(function(id) {
    console.log(" Fetched " + id);
  });
}

var ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
Promise.map(ids, fetch, { concurrency: 3 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.1/bluebird.min.js"></script>

<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

i'd recommend using throat just for this: https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/throat

Answer (score 1):

Divide your data into as many arrays as you want concurrent connections.  Schedule with setTimeout, and have the completion callback handle the rest of the sub-array.

Wrap the setTimeout in a function of its own so that the variable values are frozen to their values at the time of delayed_fetch() invocation.

```
function delayed_fetch(delay, namespace, id, issueIds, filters) {
  setTimeout(
    function() { 
      var issueId=issueIds.shift();
      github.fetchIssue(namespace, id, issueId, filters).then(function(response) {
        console.log('Writing: ' + issueId);
        writeIssueToDisk(fetchIssueCallback(response));
        delayed_fetch(0, namespace, id, issueIds, filters);
      });
    }, delay);
}

var i=0;
_.each([ [1,2] , [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,10] ], function(issueIds) {
        var delay=++i*200; // millisecond
        delayed_fetch(delay, repo.namespace, repo.id, issueIds, filters);
});
```

Comment: Wastes time. If a bucket has five items where four finish in 100ms and one in 10s, your code will spend 100ms with concurrency of 5, and 9.1s with concurrency of 1, before moving on.

Comment: Sure, but this specific example involves tasks of equivalent weight and, in practice, will work just fine.  It's conceptually simpler than the alternative, which involves variable-scope-hell and a supervisor loop.  jfriend00's solution is longer than mine already, and needs to be about twice as long again to actually solve the problem.

Comment: Given that OP has confirmed he uses at least three libraries already (lodash or underscore, Q and whatever `github.fetchIssue` comes from), both jfriend00's solution and mine are one line only. Besides, I fail to see anything in his post that could be described as "variable-scope-hell", and a loop already exists in OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using Bluebird

```
function getUserFunc(user) {
  //Get a collection of user
}

function getImageFunc(id) {
  //get a collection of image profile based on id of the user
}

function search(response) {
  return getUsersFunc(response).then(response => {
    const promises = response.map(items => return items.id);
    const images = id => {
        return getImagesFunc(id).then(items => items.image);
    };
    return Promise.map(promises, images, { concurrency: 5 });
  });
}
```

Previously i used ES6 function `Promise.all()`, but it doesn't work like what i'm expecting. Then go with third party library bluebird.js and Work like a charm.